# Iterate over heterogeneous list

Tags: java, loops, data-structures, collections

I have a method which returns the list like

```
public List<Object> getSomeData(SomeBean sb) {
    List<Object> data = Lists.newArrayList();
    data.add(sb.getId());  // Id->long
    data.add(sb.getName()); // name->String
    .....
    return data;
}
```

and Now I have to iterate over this list, which I have to check type every time as

```
        for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
            if (data.get(i) instanceof String) {
                 //append
            } 
            if (data.get(i) instanceof Long) {
               //append
            } 
         ....
        }
```

I need to append the elements of list in the loop.
Are their any better way to achieve this, may be without using instanceof operator.

Comment: Why are you adding names and ids to the same list? If they have a relationship, you can use a class to define that relationship. If they don't - they shouldn't be on the same list.

Comment: Having such a list is the problem in the first place.  If you have to mix objects of different types, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a class for that data and return an instance of it instead of a `List`.

```
class SomeEntity {
  long id;
  String name;

  public SomeEntity(long id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  @Overrides
  public String toString() {
    return id + " " + name;
  }
}
```

Just use it in your code:

```
public SomeEntity getSomeData(SomeBean sb) {
    SomeEntity entity = new SomeEntity(sb.getId(), sb.getName());
    return entity;
}
```

Edit: you can override the `toString()` method of the class and use it in your code (added above)

Comment: Actually I have to append the elements of list in the loop.

Comment: @Abs Override the toString() method

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
    final List<Object> someData = new ArrayList<>();
    someData.add("stringValue"); //String 
    someData.add(1L); //Long Value

    final String result = someData.stream()
    .map(String::valueOf)
    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));

    System.out.println(result);
```